# unit test a service based on BroadcastReceiver getting list of wifi's SSID and returning Rx.Observable

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java, android-testing, rx-android

I am  trying to test unit my ServiceHelper class that is providing a list of Wifi's SSID to show in my view. 
So I am providing an observable using RxJava + RxAndroid. As you can see I have chosen the Observable.create() to create from native my observable (Arraylist of Items) witch is depending on a BroadcastReciever inner class.
I need to test unit this method. I don't have a good idea about how to test or mock this kind of service that does depend on Sensors.

```
public class WifiPhoneServiceHelper {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> ssidList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<ScanResult> scanResultList;
private WifiManager wifiManager;

public WifiPhoneServiceHelper(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public Observable<ArrayList<String>> getObservableSsidWifiList() {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<ArrayList<String>>() {

        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super ArrayList<String>> subscriber) {
            wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

            final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
                        scanResultList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                        for (int i = 0; i < scanResultList.size(); i++) {
                            String ssidDetected = scanResultList.get(i).SSID;
                            ssidList.add(ssidDetected);
                        }
                        subscriber.onNext(ssidList);
                    }
                }
            };

            context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

            if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            }
            wifiManager.startScan();

            subscriber.add(new MainThreadSubscription() {
                @Override
                protected void onUnsubscribe() {
                    context.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                    Timber.d("unregisterReceiver BroadcastReceiver SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION");
                    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                        subscriber.unsubscribe();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to unit test your code you need to description of all functionality into separate interface and then implement it for Android and create mock implementation for unit tests (Mockito).

Comment: So I can really test the provided list of Wifi-SSIDs using a real Android Phone device ? I mean what can I do to not test the whole application in runtime ... I want to test the provided list of WIFI'ssid  by using the android API from the SDK

Comment: No, unit tests run on java machine, to test on Android use instrumented tests. By doing so you'll have real Context of Android

Comment: Ok understood so how can I so use an instrumented test to list this list of wifi-ssid? 
I can't find one example that works ... may be because am not that expert in testing ... Can you post a link of testing code ? thanks in advance...

Comment: project by default has empty Instrumented test, see androidTest folder

Answer (score 1):

Alex effectively suggests that you create an interface between your code and the Wi-Fi system, and in production code have it implemented by Android's WifiManager, but in testing, implemented by your own test harness.

You could certainly do that but another option is [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/). This is an Android unit test framework that can be used to mock large parts of the Android system without doing as much groundwork as you would with Mockito. Specifically it can mock the Wi-Fi system and therefore you can have it pretend that a given network exists or doesn't. The advantages to this are you can largely leave your Wi-Fi using code as it is, without heavy refactoring for test, but you still don't need a real device and it's not dependent on the real world's networking environment.

In particular look for examples based around [ShadowWifiManager](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowWifiManager.html). The other half of the puzzle is producing event broadcasts to stimulate your code, but this should also be feasible.

It's beyond the scope of this answer to fully describe the establishment of a Robolectric test environment, but hopefully that gives you something to begin researching around.

Comment: Thank you, so I need to divide this job into two steps:
Step 1: 
I have to use an interface called for example 
interface IWifiSsidProvider {
ArrayList<String> provideSsidWifiList(Context context );
}
then I use its real world implementation in my getObservableSsidWifiList()
-Step two is to mock the wifi system using ShadowWifiManager of Robotelectics . 
But what if I want to be really sure that this code is really providing a list of SSID and does'nt crash in runtime ? 
is there any way how to test it with a real device using an instrumented test for example ? 
And thanks a lot !

Comment: Rather than two steps, we have described two different possibilities. You don't need to interface it out (step 1) if you're using Robolectric. But if you want to test on a real device on real networks, you actually want a *third* option, which is to run the real code under instrumentation - pretty much just a normal unit test of your existing code, but using a device. There's plenty of material out there describing how to do instrumented tests on Android.

Comment: Thank you Rob, now I can see it clearly , please write some helpful links so I can finish this conversation . :)